# Creating AX order through a REST API

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, rest, axapta

If a side company have Microsoft Dynamics AX service running (in which they can create orders, import orders from files and etc.) and now we want to be able to get orders through a REST API from other clients. Is it possible to create order through REST?

I didn't found any information online, and the database has over 1 billion rows of information.

I can easily take information from the database, but inserting into it is very problematic.

Is it possible?

**EDIT:
AX version: Microsoft Business Solutions-Axapta Version 3.0**

Comment: Please specify which version of AX you are using

Comment: Curently I am stuck on getting  last row INVENTTRANSID value from table SALESLINE. Because INVENTTRANSID  is string with several letters in front of string (like MM18595485). It is not set as PK, but it is required and can't be repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axapta 3.0 doesn't support webservices out of the box but it has a COM+ connector.

You shouldn't try inserting sales orders directly into the database as you will mess up stock reservations and inventory transactions really easily.

What you should do is create a REST webservice in the technology of your choice which uses the COM+ connector to call classes and methods in Axapta through the connector.

I personally have done something like this using ASP.NET MVC by adding a reference to the COM connector in my project and calling a custom class I created inside AX.

It's probably going to be a bit difficult to find a lot of documentation for a product that old (and the com connector was replaced by a .NET business connector in recent versions) but the API is basically still the same as the .NET Business Connector.

Some links that could help get you started

- https://ismailozcan68.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/dynamics-axapta-sales-orders-business-connector/
- https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/dynamicsaxposed/archive/2011/10/11/how-to-create-sales-order-through-code
- http://axaptafreak.blogspot.com/2005/07/how-to-set-up-com-for-axapta-correctly.html

Comment: Thank You very much. Gonna go read all articles and try to implement suggested solution :)